# Possible Infinite Loop error with multiple-key Caesar Cipher

Tags: java, queue, encode, caesar-cipher

This program compiles, but after I enter the individual key values, the program does not output anything (no errors), and effectively ends. It's supposed to shift each character by a different amount using the list of key values. For example, if the key values are 3 1 7 -4 2 5, the first character is shifted by 3, the second by 1, and so on(On the ASCII character chart). After shifting the sixth character by 5, I start using the key over again. I have already implemented a Node and Queue class for the Queue interface.

Here is my class:

```
public class Cipher
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        Queue keys = new Queue();
        int n;
    String answer, message, encrypted = "", decrypted = "";

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the number of key values:");
            n = kb.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter the individual key values:");

            while (kb.hasNextInt())
                keys.enqueue((Integer)kb.nextInt());

            int initial = Integer.parseInt((String)keys.peek());

            System.out.println("Enter a string to be encoded:");
            message = kb.nextLine();

            for(int j=0; j < message.length(); j++)
            {
                keys.enqueue(keys.peek());
                encrypted += encode(message.charAt(j), Integer.parseInt((String)keys.dequeue()));
            }

            System.out.println("The encoded message is: " + encrypted);

            while (Integer.parseInt((String)keys.peek()) != initial)
            {
                keys.enqueue(keys.peek());
                keys.dequeue();
            }

            for(int k = 0; k < message.length(); k++)
            {
                keys.enqueue(keys.peek());
                decrypted += decode(message.charAt(k), Integer.parseInt((String)keys.dequeue()));
            }

            System.out.println("The decoded message is:" + decrypted);
            System.out.println("Would you like to run the program again? (yes/no)");
            answer = kb.nextLine();
        }
        while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
    }

    public static String decode(char enc, int offset) {
        return encode(enc, 26-offset);
    }

    public static String encode(char enc, int offset) {
        offset = offset % 26 + 26;
        StringBuilder encoded = new StringBuilder();
        if (Character.isUpperCase(enc)) {
                encoded.append((char) ('A' + (enc - 'A' + offset) % 26 ));
                }
         else {
                encoded.append((char) ('a' + (enc - 'a' + offset) % 26 ));
                }
        return encoded.toString();
    }
}
```

I believe the error has something to do with this while loop:

```
System.out.println("Enter the individual key values:");

            while (kb.hasNextInt())
                keys.enqueue((Integer)kb.nextInt());

            int initial = Integer.parseInt((String)keys.peek());
```

Comment: it can  debug by yourself

Comment: Just one point. Using a deque for what is simply a circular buffer is akin to trying to kill a mosquito with a thermo-nuke (i.e., will probably work (unless it's North Korean) but it's serious overkill). Now if only I could have brought myself to care about Java, I might have been able to provide an answer :-)

Comment: You've got an interesting situation; You refer to the ASCII character set, yet are writing an `encode` function that takes a `char`, which is a UTF-16 code unit. UTF-16 is one encoding for the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set. Parameter validation is used to give bounds to the range of data acceptable to an algorithm. Consider, `if (!Character.UnicodeBlock.BASIC_LATIN.equals(Character.UnicodeBlock.of(enc)) || !Character.isLetter(enc)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only letter codepoints in the C0 Controls and Basic Latin block are allowed"); `